# changing a component's attribute in a subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am using angular4 to develop my front end part.I have a service which return an observable to which i want to suubscribe in my component.So how can i change the component's attribute after loading the data in the subscribe method  and to remain even after the ngOnInit method and not return to it's default value.
This is my component's code:

```
import {CreateUserComponent} from '../create-user/create-user.component';
import {UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent} from '../update-users-credentials/update-users-credentials.component';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import{UsersListService} from '../shared/users-list.service'
import { User } from 'app/pages/Users/shared/user';
@Component({
  selector: 'vr-users-list',
  templateUrl: './users-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-list.component.scss']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  private users:any[]=["1","2","3"];
  private selectedUser:User;
  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,private userListService: UsersListService) { 
  }

    public get $selectedUser(): User {
        return this.selectedUser;
    }

    public set $selectedUser(value: User) {
        this.selectedUser = value;
    }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.userListService.getUserList().subscribe (
    data =>{
    console.log("those are data "+data.length);    
    this.users=data;


});


  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.userListService.getUserList().subscribe (
      data =>{
      console.log("those are data "+data.length);    
      this.users=data;


  });

  }
  openUsersDetails() {


    let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    let dialogRef:MdDialogRef<UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent> = this.dialog.open(UpdateUsersCredentialsComponent, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.email =this.selectedUser.$email;
  }
  openCreateUser() {
    this.dialog.open( CreateUserComponent);
  }

}
```

this is the getUserList method

```
getUserList(){
    //this method is returning the items 
            return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
            .map(res => {
                this.users=res['items'];
               return this.users;
            });

        }
```

Comment: It will be useful if you show how are you emitting values from your Observable on your service, show us your code on getUserList() method!

Comment: i have already updated the post

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using ngAfterViewInit() to make another subscription in order to update users variable right?

As you are injecting your service instance on the constructor you can access directly to 'this.users' variable of the service on your template and in your component. For example:

On your service, just use getUserList method to save the response on users variable, as you see without a return statement:

```
getUserList(){
//this method is returning the items 
        return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
        .map(res => {
            this.users=res['items'];
        });

    }
```

On the component you could do a function:

```
getUsersFromService () {
    return this.userListService.users
}
```

And then, whenever you need the access this variable you need to call getUsersFromService()

You could also access userListService.users on the template but if you do AOT compilation you will get some errors because userListService is a private variable.

If you need to make another GET request to your backend simply call function like this on your component:

```
 refreshUsers () { 
    this.userListService.get().subscribe()
}
```

This method will refresh users variable of the service (and you will see that the value might change on your template because it is an Observable)

Comment: same problem :/

Comment: 'So how can i change the component's attribute after loading the data in the subscribe method and to remain even after the ngOnInit method and not return to it's default value'.... You should be able to do that by changing userListService.users variable! Try do make a method (on your component) in which you change it's value and then put it on your template like this {{ userListService.users }}